# Expected number of blue balls in an independent selection from balls of $3$ different colours

Tags: probability, expectation

$3$ persons $A, B\ \&\ C$ has $10$ balls each. The colours of their balls are given in the table below.
\begin{align}
& Person & Red & & Blue & & Green \\ \hline
& A & 6 & & 3 & & 1 \\ \hline
& B & 2 & & 2 & & 6 \\ \hline
& C & 2 & & 1 & & 7 \\ \hline
\end{align}
Now each one of them picks up a ball arbitrarily and gives to another person $D$. Their choices are independent of each other.

We are to find out the the expected number of blue balls $D$ will have.

> My approach:
>
> \begin{align}
> & P(A_{blue}) & = & &\frac{3}{10} & \tag{i} \\
> & P(\overline{A_{blue}}) & = & &\frac{7}{10} & \tag{ii} \\
> & P(B_{blue}) & = & &\frac{2}{10} & \tag{iii} \\
> & P(\overline{B_{blue}}) & = & &\frac{8}{10} & \tag{iv} \\
> & P(C_{blue}) & = & &\frac{1}{10} & \tag{v} \\
> & P(\overline{C_{blue}}) & = & &\frac{9}{10} & \tag{vi} \\
> \end{align}
>   $P(A_{blue}) \equiv$ $A$'s probability of selecting $1$ blue ball.
>
> Let by $P(D_n)$ we denote $D$'s probability of having $n$ ***blue balls***.
>
> So,
>   \begin{align}
> & P(D_1) & = & & (i).(iv).(vi) + (ii).(iii).(vi) + (ii).(iv).(v) & & = & & \frac{398}{1000} \\
> & P(D_2) & = & & (i).(iii).(vi) + (ii).(iii).(v) + (i).(iv).(v) & & = & & \frac{92}{1000} \\
> & P(D_3) & = & & (i).(iii).(v) & & = & & \frac{6}{1000} \\
> \end{align}
>
> $\therefore E(D)\equiv$ Expected number of blue balls received by $D$ = $1.P(D_1) + 2.P(D_2) + 3.P(D_3) = \frac{6}{10}$,
>   which is the exact same result as $P(A_{blue}) + P(B_{blue}) + P(C_{blue})$ (**is this coincidental ?**)

Is there any other elegant method for doing this ? (mine is too naive I suppose)

Comment: Blue balls ? *Really* ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not coincidental.

Let $X_{A},X_{B},X_{C}$ denote the number of blue balls that $D$
receives from $A,B,C$ respectively. Then $D$ will receive $X:=X_{A}+X_{B}+X_{C}$
blue balls in total, and:

$$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}\left(X_{A}+X_{B}+X_{C}\right)=\mathbb{E}X_{A}+\mathbb{E}X_{B}+\mathbb{E}X_{C}=\frac{3}{10}+\frac{2}{10}+\frac{1}{10}=\frac{6}{10}$$

Here e.g. $X_{A}$ takes values in $\left\{ 0,1\right\} $ with $P\left\{ X_{A}=0\right\} =\frac{7}{10}$
and $P\left\{ X_{A}=1\right\} =\frac{3}{10}$ wich leads to $\mathbb{E}X_{A}=\frac{3}{10}=P\left\{ X_{A}=1\right\} =P\left(A_{blue}\right)$. Likewise $\mathbb{E}X_{B}=P\left(B_{blue}\right)$ and $\mathbb{E}X_{C}=P\left(C_{blue}\right)$.

Finding an expectation is often more easy then finding a distribution. Always try that route first.